# How do I prepend a new item to an ng-repeat list?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have situations where I need to prepend an item to a list that is initially generated using `ng-repeat`. How do I do this?

```
<div ng-click="prependItem()>Click Here</div>
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="someClass">Item name: {{item.name}}</div>
    <div class="anotherClass">Item type: {{item.type}}</div>
</div>
```

If I click on `prependItem()` I want want the new item to be added to the top of the list. Obviously, I don't want to regenerate the entire `ng-repeat`. I've been unable to find any documentation that would explain how to do this. Thank ahead of time for any help!

Comment: Add the item at the beginning of `items` collection. It will appear on screen automatically.

Comment: Yes, but how do I do that?

Answer (score 16):

```
scope.prependItem = function (newItem) {
    items.unshift(newItem);
};
```

AngularJS is smart enough to know the addition, and only create html element for it
http://plnkr.co/edit/qzIfzSP6buiQ49rDreNk?p=preview

You can see from console that only the newly added item will log messages

Comment: This adds a new item, but none of my data is filled in the newly prepended item. That is, ``{{item.name}}`` and ``{{item.type}}`` are blank.

Comment: Because i don't know the values, i just commented with `/* your item */`. You could replace it with the data you want, e.g. `items.unshift({name: '3', type: 'B'});`. Please check the plunk for reference

Answer (score 0):

ng-repeat will rebuild the list if you add an item to the front of your array. If you add it to the end it's smarter in that it will only update the DOM to reflect the change for the one item you've added in.

Because you've added an item to the front, it has to move everything in the DOM so I think it just rebuilds it as it's easier to do than moving (don't quote me on that though lol). It isn't necessarily a bad thing to rebuild that list (unless it's huge, you won't even notice the refresh, if it is very big, I'd recommend showing a spinner whilst it rebuilds the html, that's the approach we've taken at work; since the user has clicked the button they're expecting the interaction so the spinner seemed like the best compromise whilst angular rerendered).